# How to change the color of bibitems?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, color

I'm showing my references at the end of my `beamer` presentation.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\frame{
     \begin{thebibliography}{1}\scriptsize
        \bibitem{Test} Test, Me, 2015.
     \end{thebibliography}
}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to change the color of every whole `\bibitem` line to something else, black for example. How can I do that without affecting the rest of my presentation? I've been looking and Googling for hours, but I can't find a way to do it. I tried things like

```
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black}
```

and

```
\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=black}
```

but the first one changes about my whole colour palette and the second one doesn't do anything. What am I missing?

Comment: Try with `bibliography entry author`, `bibliography entry title`, `bibliography entry location` and `bibliography entry note` beamer-template/font/color...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The colour of a `bibitem` can be set separately for the `author`, the `title` and additional fields like `location` or `note`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=blue} 
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{fg=green} 
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=cyan}  

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Example bibliography}
        \begin{thebibliography}{3}
            \bibitem[{Alpher} et~al.(1948) {Alpher}, {Bethe}, \& {Gamow}]{paper}
            Alpher, R. A., Bethe, H. \& Gamow, G. 
            \newblock{The Origin of Chemical Elements}.
            \newblock{\emph{Phys. Rev.}, 73:\penalty0 803--804, Apr. 1948.}
            \newblock{doi: 10.1103/PhysRev.73.803}
        \end{thebibliography}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here's a couple links that provide some related documentation: https://pastebin.com/nK3BWG5v and  www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf , found via https://joerglenhard.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/beamer-customization-colors/

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks