# Change bibtex color in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, bibtex, beamer-metropolis

In my beamer presentation item in bibliography looks like this:

[image]

How i can remove this color changes? I need it all without bold font and in black, not gray.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption,ragged2e,enumerate}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    \cite{Zim:07} \cite{Dal:88}
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
    \bibliographystyle{ugost2008}
    \bibliography{bl}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

bl.bib:

```
@Book{Zim:07,
  author   = {P. Zimbardo},
  title    = {Lucifer Effect Understanding How Good People Turn Evil [Текст]},
  year     = {2007},
  language = {russian},
}

@InBook{Dal:88,
  author   = {В.И. Даль},
  title    = {Толковый словарь живого Великорусского языка, том второй [Текст]},
  year     = {1881},
  language = {russian},
  pages    = {807},
}
```

[MWE on the sharelatex.](https://www.sharelatex.com/read/vthpwcmjzbzq)

Comment: for the colour, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226378/36296

Comment: For the same templates as the colours you want to set the font with `series=\normalfont`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think black text colour would look good, as this is not the color of the rest of the presentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption,ragged2e,enumerate}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Zim:07,
  author   = {P. Zimbardo},
  title    = {Lucifer Effect Understanding How Good People Turn Evil [Текст]},
  year     = {2007},
  language = {russian},
}

@InBook{Dal:88,
  author   = {В.И. Даль},
  title    = {Толковый словарь живого Великорусского языка, том второй [Текст]},
  year     = {1881},
  language = {russian},
  pages    = {807},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=mDarkTeal}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=mDarkTeal} 
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{fg=mDarkTeal} 
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=mDarkTeal}  

\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{series=\normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{series=\normalfont} 
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{series=\normalfont} 
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{series=\normalfont} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    \cite{Zim:07} \cite{Dal:88}
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
    \bibliographystyle{ugost2008}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]