# How to customize the colors of `biblatex` bibliography entries in `beamer`?

Tags: beamer, biblatex

When using `biblatex` in `beamer`, the list of references becomes colored. The pattern in colors I see is as follows

1. Author names are in dark purple
2. Title of entry is in black
3. Entries after main title are in light purple
4. Links and DOIs are the same color as inlined math specified by `\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=<color>}`. They become light purple when `\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}` is not explicitly included
5. Bibliography labels take the color of itemization labels specified by `\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=<color>}`

[image]

**Question 1:** how to reset all colors except links and DOIs to black?

**Question 2:** how to customize the color of what precedes and follows titles (i.e., dark purple and light purple)

**Question 3:** how to customize the color of the title itself?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@article{aldaoudeyeh2016,
    title={Photovoltaic-battery scheme to enhance PV array characteristics in partial shading conditions},
    author={Aldaoudeyeh, Al-Motasem},
    journal={IET Renewable Power Generation},
    volume={10},
    number={1},
    pages={108--115},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IET}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{aldaoudeyeh2017,
    author={A. M. I. Aldaoudeyeh and R. G. Kavasseri and I. T. Lima},
    booktitle={2017 Ninth Annual IEEE Green Technologies Conference (GreenTech)},
    title={Characterization of Forward Electricity Market Price Variations and Price-Responsive Demand},
    year={2017},
    pages={211-218},
    keywords={Adaptation models;Computational modeling;Elasticity;Electricity supply industry;Estimation;Load modeling;Real-time systems;consumption scheduling;electricity markets;peak load;real time pricing;smart metering},
    doi={10.1109/GreenTech.2017.37},
    month=Mar
}
@online{AusgridElasticity2015,
    title = {Ausgrid - Tariff structure statement},
    year = {2015},
    url = {https://www.aer.gov.au/networks-pipelines/determinations-access-arrangements/pricing-proposals-tariffs/ausgrid-tariff-structure-statement-2015},
    urldate = {2016-09-25}
}
@phdthesis{javadi2017phd,
    title={New Implication of Short Circuit Analysis in Assessing Impact of Renewable Energy Resources on System Strength of a Power Grid},
    author={Javadi, Milad},
    year={2017},
    school={University of Oklahoma}
}
@book{eremia2013,
    title={Handbook of Electrical Power System Dynamics: Modeling, Stability, and Control},
    author={Eremia, Mircea and Shahidehpour, Mohammad},
    volume={92},
    year={2013},
    publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{References}
    
    \setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=DodgerBlue3}
    \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=DodgerBlue3}
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \printbibliography

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225218/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This might be customized using the command

`\setbeamercolor{<type>}{fg=<color>}`. What to substitute in `<type>` might be

- `bibliography item` for labels
- `bibliography entry author`, `bibliography entry title`, and `bibliography entry note` for author, title and what follows the title
- `math text inlined` for URL/DOI

For `<color>`, substitute color you want

To avoid resetting the inlined math color, set `math text inlined` locally inside the frame which contains the bibliography since this will affect the entire document (this avoids any changes to inlined math colors)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@article{aldaoudeyeh2016,
    title={Photovoltaic-battery scheme to enhance PV array characteristics in partial shading conditions},
    author={Aldaoudeyeh, Al-Motasem},
    journal={IET Renewable Power Generation},
    volume={10},
    number={1},
    pages={108--115},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IET}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{aldaoudeyeh2017,
    author={A. M. I. Aldaoudeyeh and R. G. Kavasseri and I. T. Lima},
    booktitle={2017 Ninth Annual IEEE Green Technologies Conference (GreenTech)},
    title={Characterization of Forward Electricity Market Price Variations and Price-Responsive Demand},
    year={2017},
    pages={211-218},
    keywords={Adaptation models;Computational modeling;Elasticity;Electricity supply industry;Estimation;Load modeling;Real-time systems;consumption scheduling;electricity markets;peak load;real time pricing;smart metering},
    doi={10.1109/GreenTech.2017.37},
    month=Mar
}
@online{AusgridElasticity2015,
    title = {Ausgrid - Tariff structure statement},
    year = {2015},
    url = {https://www.aer.gov.au/networks-pipelines/determinations-access-arrangements/pricing-proposals-tariffs/ausgrid-tariff-structure-statement-2015},
    urldate = {2016-09-25}
}
@phdthesis{javadi2017phd,
    title={New Implication of Short Circuit Analysis in Assessing Impact of Renewable Energy Resources on System Strength of a Power Grid},
    author={Javadi, Milad},
    year={2017},
    school={University of Oklahoma}
}
@book{eremia2013,
    title={Handbook of Electrical Power System Dynamics: Modeling, Stability, and Control},
    author={Eremia, Mircea and Shahidehpour, Mohammad},
    volume={92},
    year={2013},
    publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{References}
    
    % Customize colors
        
        % Label
        \setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=SlateBlue2}
        
        % Author, title, note
        \setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=SlateBlue2}
        \setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
        \setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
        
        % URL/DOI
        \setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=DodgerBlue3}
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \printbibliography

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```